# Host SMBus controller not enabled! (VMWare 12.5.x, Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I set up a new Ubuntu 17.04 virtual machine in VMWare Workstation Pro 12.5.9 on my Windows 10 computer. I was able to set up and log into it a couple of times. All of a sudden, I cannot log into it any more, because of the following error:

```
[    3.448236] sd 32:0:0:0 [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
/dev/sda1: clean, 183684/2293760 files, 2165375/9174528 blocks
[    8.132673] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07:3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!
```

After this, I still get the graphical login screen, but any attempt to log in results in the same message and reverts back to the login screen. I googled the SMBus Host Controller not enabled error, and saw a few blogs posts about how to get around this error, that ranged from modifying the VMWare guest's `VMX file` to logging in as root via Advanced boot options and adding one or two blacklist lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file. None of these suggested workarounds helped, either individually or as a combination. I am frustrated that an OOTB VM setup like this can go awry. I appreciate any suggestions to fix this problem!

Comment: Did you execute `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` after modifying `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if your partition is not full. In my case I have created 30 GB of partition which was exhausted pretty quickly. Tried everything from this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/691729/piix4-smbus-0000007-3-host-smbus-controller-bus-not-enabled

Nothing have worked. I run Ubuntu from liveCD. Even though the partion showed 1.2 GB of free memory, after a while of tweaking and hair pulling I noticed it suddenly showed 0 free memory so I extended it to 40GB and voila everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands - 
Step 1 Run this command : `$ blkid`

You should get two partitions

1. `/dev/sda1` – Root partition
2. `/dev/sda5` – Swap partition

Step 2: Now to fix the bad sectors from the partitions, just run the `fsck `command with the partition path. Below are the commands:

```bash
$ fsck /dev/sda1 -y
$ fsck /dev/sda5 -y
```

Step 3: Now just reboot the system.

```bash
$ reboot -f
```

This worked for Me

Comment: This also worked for me.